# Update a text field from multiple combo boxes

Tags: jquery, forms

I am having problems updating a text field from multiple combo boxes using jQuery.
I have a resolution field where it will display the # of persons in one room...
Each room will be delimited by "|" and will calculate the # of adults and the # of children.

So far I was able to:
When the user selects the number of rooms, I clone the fields adults / children per room.
And calculate the number of adults per room and place in one text field.

Can anybody help me out to add into this text field the # of adults and # of children in one number?

HERE IS THE WORKING EXAMPLE
http://jsfiddle.net/elation/xZMhe/

HERE IS THE HTML CODE

```
    number of rooms<br />
<select id="itemCount" name="itemCount">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<hr />
<div id="cloneWrap1">
<!-- Clone Item Start -->
  number of persons room<br />
    Adults
  <select name="cloneElement1" id="item_dup_1" class="room">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option selected value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    Children
    <select class="childrenRoom">
        <option selected value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<!-- Clone Item End -->
<hr />
</div>
Resolution rooms | persons<br />
<input type="text" name="gsNumberOfTravelers" id="gsNumberOfTravelers" value="2">
```

AND HERE THE JQUERY

```
// Convination Function # of rooms + # of pax //
jQuery.fn.fieldsManage = function (number) {
    var ele = $(this);
    var clones = ele.data("clones");
    clones = clones ? clones : new Array(ele.attr("id"));
    if (clones.length < number) {
        var clone;
        while(clones.length < number) {
            clone = ele.clone(true);
            var id = clones[0]+clones.length;
            clone.attr("id", id);
            $("#"+clones[clones.length-1]).after(clone);
            clones.push(id);
        }
    } else {
        while(clones.length > number) {
            $("#"+clones.pop()).remove();
        }
    }
    ele.data("clones", clones);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#itemCount").change(function() {
        $("#cloneWrap1").fieldsManage(this.value);
        calculateNumbers();
    });
    $('.room').live('change', function(){
        calculateNumbers();
    });
});

function calculateNumbers(){
    var gsNumberOfTravelers = [];
    $('.room').each(function(){
        gsNumberOfTravelers.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("[name='gsNumberOfTravelers']").val(gsNumberOfTravelers.join('|'));
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'in one number' ... How you mean?

Comment: elation, when you say 'in one number' you mean that the adults and children are added together for each room. For example, if a room had 3 adults and 1 child you would want to see the number 4 for that room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a little for both the HTML jQuery.

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9w43/) to make sure that's what you're looking for.

### What happens

For each room, we add up the adults and children and put that total in an array. That array is then put into a text field.

### How

Basically what I have done is removed the `room` class from the `select` elements and moved it to the cloned `div`. I did this so that you can easily loop the rooms. Once you have that, you simply iterated over the `selects` which I have given a class of `person`.

Here is the relevant jQuery

```
function calculateNumbers(){
    //initialize variables
    var gsNumberOfTravelers = [];
    var total = 0;

    //loop over each room
    $('.room').each(function() {
        total = 0;

        //loop over the persons that are apart of the current room
        $(this).children('.person').each(function(){
            //add to a total
            total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        //push the total of the room to the room array
        gsNumberOfTravelers.push(total);
    });


    $("[name='gsNumberOfTravelers']").val(gsNumberOfTravelers.join('|'));
};
```

And here is the relevant HTML

```
<div id="cloneWrap1" class="room">
<!-- Clone Item Start -->
          number of persons room<br />
            Adults
          <select name="cloneElement1" id="item_dup_1" class="person">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option selected value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            Children
            <select class="childrenRoom person">
                <option selected value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```